# Why array expression in Angular view not working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

To convert a field's value into a display name, I am using expressions in the view as one line. For example, the backend sends gender as 'M' for male and 'F' for female, for this I have written the view as:

```
<td>{{ {'M': "Male", 'F': "Femail"} [partB.gender] }}</td>
```

and it worked fine.

I have fair number of [choice fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#choices) in my django model. One of them is a boolean received as `true`/`false` and to display that field as "Yes"/"No" I have written expression in the view as:

```
<td>
 {{ ["No", "Yes"][+partB.is_employee_with_substantial_interest] }}
</td>
```

but **this is not working**.

I thought it could be a precedence issue between `.` and unary `+` but it is not. Check:

```
>> var a = {a: true, b: false}
undefined
>> a.a
true
>> +a.a
1
```

As far as I know JavaScript the expression `["No", "Yes"][+partB.is_employee_with_substantial_interest]` itself is not wrong.

Before asking the question here I tried to figure it out myself on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L48ZOO1ImDhJQhAvjFZa?p=preview)

```html
<html ng-app="myApp" >
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <h1>AngularJS Template Query </h1>

   <h4> JavaScript Working </h4>
   <ul>
   <li id="a"> Grijesh Chauhan  </li>
   <li id="b"> Grijesh Chauhan  </li>
   <li id="c"> Grijesh Chauhan  </li>
   <li id="d"> Grijesh Chauhan  </li>
   <li id="e"> Grijesh Chauhan  </li>
   </ul>

  <div>

  <h4> Angular Code not Working </h4>
  
  <ul>
<li> {{ ["No", "Yes"][+data.b] }} </li>
<li> {{ ["No", "Yes"][+data.a] }} </li>
<li> {{ { true: "Yes", false: "No"}[data.b]  }} </li>
<li> {{ { true: "Yes", false: "No"}[data.a]  }} </li>
<li> {{ { 1: "Yes", 0: "No"}[+data.b]  }} </li>
<li> {{ { 1: "Yes", 0: "No"}[+data.a]  }} </li>
   </ul>
 
  </div>
  
  <script>
 var  data = {a: true, b: false};
 
 document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = ["No", "Yes"][+data.a];
 document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = ["No", "Yes"][+data.b];
 document.getElementById('c').innerHTML = { 1: "Yes", 0: "No"}[+data.b];
 document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = { 1: "Yes", 0: "No"}[+data.a]; 
 document.getElementById('e').innerHTML = { true: "Yes", false: "No"}[data.a]; 
  </script>
  <script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = { a: true, b: false };
});
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has is own evaluation function. He's not jsut performing a eval() behind the scene. So some things that works in Javascript just doesn't work with angular expression.

On the oppsite some thing works in Angular that crash in javascript for instance

```
a.b.c.d == true
```

Will crash on JS if a or b or c is not defined, in angular expression this will work no need for

```
a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d
```

For your problem you may try

```
<li> {{ { "true": "Yes", "false": "No"}["\""+data.a+"\""]  }} </li>
```

Or something like this that try to transform the boolean values in string.

Other workaround more common

```
<li ng-if="data.a">Yes</li>
<li ng-if="!data.a">No</li>
```

This is more verbose but more readable in the end IMO.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion is helpful. I will change my expression using `ng-if`